# How can I limit the items in the FlatList and add load more?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

My skills is basic, and I'm new to React Native. I want to limit the posts in 12 and when the user scrolls, automatically load more posts.

**My Code:**

```
export default class Posts extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  isLoading: true,};}

componentDidMount() {
   return fetch(ConfigApp.URL+'json/data_posts.php')
     .then((response) => response.json())
     .then((responseJson) => {
       this.setState({
         isLoading: false,
         dataPosts: responseJson
       }, function() {
       });
     })
     .catch((error) => {
     });}

render() {
return (
    <FlatList
      data={ this.state.dataPosts }
      numColumns={2}
      renderItem={({item}) =>
            <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={1} style={{flex: 1}}>
            <View style={{margin: 5, marginLeft: 4}}>
            <ImageBackground source={{uri: ConfigApp.IMAGESFOLDER+item.post_image}}>
                <LinearGradient colors={['rgba(0,0,0,0.3)', 'rgba(0,0,0,0.8)']}>
                        <Text numberOfLines={2}>{item.post_title}</Text>
                </LinearGradient>
            </ImageBackground>
            </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}

    />
);}}
```

Comment: Do you want to load more data from the server or do you load them all at once and only display 12 of them initially?

Comment: yes, the second option

Comment: How much data length do you get initially, is there any limit on the api to call next set of items?

Comment: i found this library, but i don't know how i can use it https://github.com/BBuzzArt/react-native-infinite

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your requirement is to append the existing list from already pulled data in a chunk of 12, then you may consider the following strategy which uses `onEndReached` and `onEndThreshold` to handle the scroll and add 12 records at a time.

Set the current `page` number to `0` in the constructor:

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    ... ,
    page: 0,
    posts: []
  }
}
```

Inside `componentDidMount`, you need to pull all data from the server and store it in the local state (which you are currently doing), then call the function which will read the first 12 records.

```
componentDidMount() {
   return fetch(ConfigApp.URL+'json/data_posts.php')
   .then((response) => response.json())
   .then((responseJson) => {
     this.setState({
       isLoading: false,
       page: 0,
       dataPosts: responseJson
     }, function() {
       // Call the function to pull initial 12 records
       this.addRecords(0);
     });
   })
   .catch((error) => {
   });
}
```

Now add the function which will add records from `this.state.dataPosts`:

```
addRecords = (page) => {
  // Assuming this.state.dataPosts hold all the records
  const newRecords = []
  for(var i = page * 12, il = i + 12; i < il && i <
    this.state.dataPosts.length; i++){
    newRecords.push(this.state.dataPosts[i]);
  }
  this.setState({
    posts: [...this.state.posts, ...newRecords]
  });
}
```

Now add the scroll handler:

```
onScrollHandler = () => {
  this.setState({
    page: this.state.page + 1
  }, () => {
    this.addRecords(this.state.page);
  });
}
```

Render function

```
render() {
  return(
    ...
    <FlatList
       ...
       data={this.state.posts}
       renderItem={({item}) => ... }
       keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
       onEndReached={this.onScrollHandler}
       onEndThreshold={0}
    />
    ...
  );
}
```

Comment: I test it, but i get this error TypeError: undefined is not an object evaluating '_this.state.records[i]'

Comment: My fault, it will be `dataPosts`. I will update answer.

Comment: I have updated the answer, please check `addRecords`.

Comment: Now i get this error : TypeError: Array.from requires an array-like object not null or undefined

Comment: I am not sure what data you are getting from backend, can you please confirm that `this.state.dataPosts` is an array.

Comment: Sorry, I missed one more thing, I have updated the answer, in the constructor, just set `posts: []`, please check,

Comment: Now load all the posts without problems, but the load more function does not work, load all the posts at once

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170474/discussion-between-prasun-pal-and-bdroid).

Comment: @Prasun how you are doing good, i know it has been a while but can you provide the same solution to a functional based component. thank you

Answer (score 8):

You *can* add the slice (start,end) method while fetching jsondata in datasource. This trick may solve your problem.

**dataPosts: responseJson.slice(0,10)**:  Replace this line with yours.

Answer (score 1):

In FlatList prop `Data` you will use `slice(start, end)`.

Example:

```
data = {Data.slice(0, 4)}
```

In the above example, flatlist will show only the first four objects.