# How to prevent React Native FlatList consumer from bloating app memory due to state data increase?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am new to React Native and `FlatList` and all the examples and tutorials I can find are very basic and don't answer my question, which is: Can `FlatList` be fed with dynamic data without increasing the memory of the application. If I hold the data into a `data` array, and that array is part of the state of the component that uses the `FlatList`, then adding dynamic data to that`data` will not scale and will consume the whole memory of the application. In other words, if I have a component like:

```
const MyApp = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => { 
     ....load 10 objects from network... 
     setData(data.concat(newData)); 
  }, []);

  const onPress = () => {
   ....load 10 more....
   setData(data.concat(newData));
  }

  return (
    <View>
     <FlatList data={data} .../>
     <Button onPress={onPress} title="Load More..."/>
    </View> 
  )
}
```

don't seem to scale for me. `data` array increases memory consumption of the app every time the `Load More...` button is clicked.

Am I wrong? If `no`, then what is the best practice to solve this problem?
If `yes`, why am I wrong?

Thank you very much in advance.

P.

Comment: Hello, have you checked virtualizedList props like maxToRenderPerBatch, initialNumToRender and removeClippedSubViews?
Also, have you provided shouldComponentUpdate or a PureComponent, and if you are using a functional component, memoization?

Comment: I have. But I don't understand how these solve the problem? the `state` (in my example `data`) will be growing and growing. I guess regardless of the settings in `FlatList`. Because they are part of the `MyApp` component and not of the `FlatList`.

Comment: I believe the amount fo memory consumed increases based on how many items are rendered over time. With these props you can control them.

Comment: See, if you are not memoizing or preventing rerendering, everytime a new item is added, the whole list will get rerendered even if they didn`t change.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50193040/how-i-can-limit-the-items-in-the-flatlist-and-add-load-more

Comment: By default FlatList will not render items that are not visible. This behavior is from VirtualizedList which FlatList is build on top of. Read the [Second Paragraph](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/virtualizedlist). I understand your concern about memory consumption, but it is your responsibility as a developer to come up with a solution that works for you. FlatList has nothing to do with you feeding data infinitely to your state. If that's what you mean.