# I am using infinite scroll in flatlist in react native but its loading more in the start of the flatlist

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

In react native flatlist the infinte scroll is triggering in the start of the flatlist and its keep on loading the data even after using the onEndReachedthreshhold ={0.4}.

Comment: did you want to limit the first load numbers?

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50193040/how-i-can-limit-the-items-in-the-flatlist-and-add-load-more