# Only showing specific number of itmes on the screen in a flatList

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am using dummyData to render items in my Flatlist. My dummyData has 30 items and I want 10 items to be shown on the window at a time. How do I do that? I am new to react native.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can define `state` for data of `flatlist` and handle that with add first 10 first number of dummy data list . and when scroll goes to down and end of list load more item.  for more info see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50193040/how-i-can-limit-the-items-in-the-flatlist-and-add-load-more)

Comment: Thank you.  This helped!